# How to generate src URL for fonts in Style sheets

Tags: css, fonts

I have one style sheet where they have written font src URL as below.
what is that number in the src URL after base 64 ?
Now I want to change the font to Forma DJR?
How can I generate that number for Forma DJR font

font-family: 'simplified-light';
src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAGgc......

Answer (score 0):

It's not a number but a base64 encoded font file.

You can use an online generator like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) or [fontsquirrel's web font generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

They both have a base 64 option to generate a data URL.

You should also update your `@font-face` rule according to your updated font.
Especially, considering the file format (woff2, woff, ttf, otf) and `font-weight`.

#### Example (using [google font "Inter"](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter))

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
}

body{
font-family:'Inter';

}
```

```html
<p>ABC <strong>ABC</strong> ABC </p>
```

**Be sure your [font license](https://www.creativebloq.com/features/font-licensing) allows webfont usage!**